# At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation

Tags: ios

At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation.
Does anyone know **why?**

Comment: Wherever you read that, don't go back and read anything else. From Apple's Documentation: "**Launch in the appropriate orientation**. If your app supports both portrait and landscape modes, it should launch using the device’s current orientation." https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/first-launch-experience/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is what says in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: Ah - well that's structural: *"...  the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism ..."* In other words, if you want a label stretching across the screen, set it up for *portrait* orientation and let the OS rotate it to *landscape* - don't define that label in landscape coordinates to begin with.